# How can we sync data in SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

We have application sage 300 ERP (Accpac) with SQL Server 2012 Express Edition, this is desktop application.

This application is hosted on a cloud system; they have provided public static IP. Client is working on cloud using Remote Desktop Connection (RDP).

The issue is that when Internet is down then client not able to access application so we have decided to install on his local machine with database.

If internet is down, then he is using local database but client wants if internet is up what he has worked that should be synced with cloud database and what other user worked on cloud that data should be synced. i.e both side data should sync.

Please help me.

Comment: How do you want to achieve that? You tagged your question with C# but this seems it could be done with sql only. Please explain yourself a little bit more

Comment: if sql not support then we can do through ado .net